# Positioning items dynamically for different screensizes

Tags: react-native

Good morning!

I'm currently trying to create a view similar to this [mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmKFd.png).

I have put down 3 different screen sizes so you can see the issue.
I have a header background image (grey box) with an angled bottom. On the right I want to display an image, which obviously needs to be positioned.

Positioning it horizontally is no issue but how can I position the image vertically? I have it positioned fixed for one screen size but obviously need to make it flexible.

Any ideas? Help would be much appreciated!

David

Comment: Can you share the code you have done so far ? 
You can use measure() for the header view (gray background), then you will get to know the height of that view, and according to that height you can place the image (circle) dynamically using position 'absolute'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use measure as @rajesh pointed out, or you can use Dimensions. As far as getting the layout consistent across devices, using position absolute and measuring the device height should allow you to get consistency across these devices.

Check out [this](https://rnplay.org/apps/pSzCKg) example I set up, it should be a good starting point at least.

[image]

https://rnplay.org/apps/pSzCKg

Comment: Wicked! Thanks both of you :)